# How can I install composer in live server cpanel

Tags: php, composer-php, cpanel

I want to use php spreadsheet package and from their site, I was told to install composer on cpanel but have met little success on the internet trying to figure out how to do it.

Please, who can put me through on how to install composer on liveserver

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH for this (alternatively using cron jobs to run the commands will also work - way more tedious)

Login to your cPanel account via SSH

Make directory for your composer (can also be used for other executables that you might store)

```
mkdir ~/composer
cd ~/composer
```

Download composer

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/download/1.6.5/composer.phar
```

Change the name of composer and make it executable

```
mv composer{.phar,}
chmod +x composer
```

You will now be able to call composer by

```
php ~/composer/composer install
```

But it's more convenient to have it run by just invoking *composer* in your terminal. For this add the ~/composer directory to your $PATH. I'm using VIM for text editing so

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Append those two lines at the bottom

```
PATH=~/composer:$PATH
export PATH
```

Exit and login via SSH again - you will be able to freely call composer in your terminal